# find no of days between 2 selected dates in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need to find number of days between 2 selected dates. I have tried the following code but it returns error results for some dates.

```
function getDateObject(str) {
  var arr = str.split("-");
  return new Date(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
}

$('#from_date,#to_date').bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    var date1 = getDateObject($('#from_date').val());
    var date2 = getDateObject($('#to_date').val());
    var days = (date2 - date1) / 86400000;
    alert(days); //it returns -1 for from:2016-01-31 - to:2016-02-01.
    //other dates like from:2016-01-13 - to:2016-01-14 returns 1 correctly
}
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: just google it.. while I typed your question title on google >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef returns same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a solution.

```
function getDateObject(str) {
  var arr = str.split("-");
  return new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2]);//just added -1 in arr[1] that is month.
}

$('#from_date,#to_date').bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    var date1 = getDateObject($('#from_date').val());
    var date2 = getDateObject($('#to_date').val());
    var days = (date2 - date1) / 86400000;
    alert(days); 
}
```

this gave me the output I needed.

Thanks you all tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your dates correctly, currently:

```
new Date("2016", "01", "31");
```

will give

```
Wed Mar 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Just this will work fine

```
// str should be in yy-mm-dd
function getDateObject(str) {
  return new Date(str);
}
```